# Different sized Images from CSS sprite on button. Use :after pseudo class to hide rest of sprite

Tags: css

I have a series of images stored horizontally in a sprite. Some are landscape photos, and others are portrait photos.

I want to display them as images on buttons, without distorting them. The landscape photos are being displayed correctly, but the portrait photos, because they are narrower, display part of the next image.

I can think of three different approaches to hide that unwanted image, but the quickest and easiest one is probably to use a *:after* pseudo class. I recall someone mentioning this technique on Stack Overflow, but now I can’t find this again. How can I do this?

Here’s my current code:

```
/* Global constants */
:root {
    --portWidth: calc(2052px / 4);  /* Width of portrait photos */
    --landWidth: calc(3264px / 4);  /* Width of landscape photos */
}

figure {display: block;
        float:left;
        border-width:thin;
}
figcaption {background-color:yellow;}

.thumb::after { content: " ";
                display: inline-block;
                width: 30em;
}

#img1, #img2, #img3 {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  object-fit: none;
}

#thumb1, #thumb2, #thumb3 {
  background: url("bates-sprite.jpeg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  object-fit: none;
  width: 30em;
  height: 30em;
  background-size: cover;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 1.5em;
}

/* Landscape photo */
#img1 {
  object-position: 0 0;
  width:  var(--landWidth);
  height: 612px; // full size 2448
}
#thumb1 { background-position: 0 0; }

/* Landscape photo */
#img2 {
  object-position: calc( var(--landWidth)  *  -1); 0;
  width:  var(--landWidth);
  height: 612px;
}
#thumb2 { background-position: -30em 0; }

/* Portrait photo */
#img3 {
  object-position: calc( ( var(--landWidth)  *  -1) * 2) 0;
  width:  var(--portWidth);
  height: calc(3101px / 4); /* full size 3101 */
}
#thumb3 { background-position: -60em 0; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<main>

<figure id="fig1">
    <figcaption>Camberley Mail</figcaption>
    <p>Text to go with picture.</p>
</figure>

<figure id="fig2">
    <figcaption>The Independent</figcaption>
    <p>Text to go with picture.</p>
</figure>

<figure id="fig3">
    <figcaption>Harry Cohen MP</figcaption>
    <p id="para">Text to go with picture.</p>
</figure>

function imgBtn (figNum) {
//  Insert a button with thumbnail image
    let html = '<button type="button" ' +
                       'class="thumb" ' +
                       'id="thumb' + figNum +
                     '" onclick="showBigImg (' + figNum + ')"></button>';
    const figcap = document.getElementById("fig" + figNum).firstElementChild;
    figcap.insertAdjacentHTML ("afterend", html);  /* Append the button to
                                                      the figcaption */
}
```

Comment: Re "`height: 612px; // full size 2448`": `//` is not a valid comment character sequence in CSS (only the C-style one is, `/*  */`). This is also indicated by the weird ***syntax highlighting***. It *will* break in some browsers (e.g., it may ignore all or part of the rest of the CSS (terminate parsing)).

Comment: The syntax highlighting here doesn't work with the *fragments* from the HTML file (it needs to be syntactically correct to work). Is it three different fragments? Two different fragments? An alternative could be to split it up in two or three parts for the syntax highlighting (use `lang-html` and `lang-javascript` (with three backticks in front)). The first part probably needs some starting HTML tags to render correctly. [A syntax highlighting reference](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109).

Answer (score 0):

You can make the image itself clickable,

```
<div class="column">
    <img src="img_lights.jpg" alt="Lights" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
</div>
```

*onclick* it would execute whatever function or instruction, in essence making the photo a button. You can shape the image to whatever size button you wanted as well with CSS.

Comment: It wasn’t, but that is interesting & gives me another possible approach.